# Case condition in inner join

Tags: sql

Can I apply case condition inside inner join?

[image]

Image showing result from tableA.

Can I join with tableB with condition when Year is null, then join tableB on ID and Country to get value from tableB.

I try something like this below but hit error 'Incorrect syntax near '=' Any advice?

```
SELECT a.*, tableB.value
from tableA a
inner join tableB on
case when year is null
then a.ID=tableB.ID
and a.Country=tableB.Country
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `left join`s:

```
select a.*, coalesce(bi.value, bc.value)  as value
from tableA a left join
     tableB bi
     on a.year is null and a.id = bi.id left join
     tableB bc
     on a.year is not null and a.country = bc.country;
```

If you want to require a match (i.e., like an `inner join`), then add:

```
where bi.id is not null or bc.id is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by *WHERE* clause.

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON b.Id = a.Id AND b.country = a.country
WHERE b.year is NULL
```